# C++ program that reverses the elements in an array

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

I've written this code to try and reverse the elements in a given array:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int numbers[6] = {1, 5, 9, 10, 12, 18};
    int b = 0;
    int a = 5;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        {
            b = numbers[i];
            numbers[i] = numbers[a-i];
            numbers[a-i] = b;
        }
    for(int c = 0; c < 6; ++c)
        cout << *(numbers) << endl;

    return 0;
    }
```

It should print out 18, 12, 10, 9, 5, 1
But when I  run the program it just prints out 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18
Where have i gone wrong? I'm guessing it is a problem within the first for loop.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive.  You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, and then construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Better use a std::vector and std::reverse. Than reversing is only one line of code. See also http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/reverse/

Comment: .. or if you use C++11, try `std::array`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change `cout << *(numbers) << endl;`

to  `cout << numbers[c] << endl;`

---

plus use the standard `reverse` algorithm from the `<algorithm>` header file:

```
  std::reverse(numbers, numbers+6);
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realise it was something that simple!

Answer (score 2):

It's the second for loop, you forgot to add c.

```
for(int c = 0; c < 6; ++c)
    cout << *(numbers + c) << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; ++i) {
    //a^=b^=a^=b; //SWAP a with b
    numbers[i] ^= numbers[ARRAY_SIZE-i] ^= numbers[i] ^= numbers[ARRAY_SIZE-i];
}
```

It will reverse all elements in array. :)